# NumberFormatter gets Hungarian currency format wrong

Tags: php, money-format, numberformatter

If I use the money_format function, it prints the currency amount in the Hungarian format correctly:

```php
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'hu_HU');
php > $number = 1234.5672;
php > echo  money_format('%n', $number)."\n";
1.234,57 Ft
```

But if I try with the NumberFormatter class it returns the wrong format

```php
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled
php > $f = new NumberFormatter('hu_HU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
php > $f->setAttribute($f::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
php > echo $f->formatCurrency('1234.5672', 'HUF')."\n";
1 234,57 Ft
```

I think it's a bug.

Comment: I have rephrased some of your question to make it more readable; and also added the php tag. If you would like to [edit] it further, please do - this site encourages editing and re-editing of questions to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: What makes you think it is a bug?  What is the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on Which operating System used. it will differ based on Windows and Linux.

Some time it doesn't work in windows